# How set text at bottom of the image using with css

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am using jQuery [Caption Plugin](http://wbotelhos.com/capty/) for display image `alt` text on image hover.

Now I want to show text bottom but currently going to top. How to fix.

What I want:

[image]

JSFiddle: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/UP5xk/)

Comment: have you tried html5 `figure` tag

Comment: Your life would be so much easier if you didn't use the `alt` text to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified plugin code:

```
 h.html('<div style="position:absolute;top:210px;">'+j.attr("alt")+'</div>');
```

Check the working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/F3rCK/

Comment: Hi Joke_Sense10 When I am putting this code in my live code I can't see text. Any Idea?

Comment: copy paste code from fiddle..did you check the fiddle?..it's working ryte?

Comment: Yes your code is prefect for me but I am checking once again.

Comment: May be you have made a syntax mistake.It's working fine in jsfiddle.Copy paste it thoroughly and check the plugin code especially.Check for missing semicolons or colons.

Comment: You can always accept the answer if you found it relevant and useful..:)

Comment: Hehehehe.. Ya Sure :)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the **documentation**, you can **copy-paste** this code

```
$('#content').capty({
  height:   46,
  opacity:  .6
});
```

And in your jsFiddle : <kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UP5xk/1/)</kbd>

```
$(function() {
    $('.default').capty({
      height:   46, // Here you init the height of your caption
      opacity:  .6
    });
});
```

Comment: Ya i have check the document but text goes up when i hover. Text must be display at bottom position.

Comment: You want the black rectangle in all your image but the text in bottom?

Comment: Hey Donovan Charpin: yup :)

Comment: I haven't a nice solution but if you play with padding, you can reproduce this effect : http://jsfiddle.net/UP5xk/6/. Otherwise, you can wrap the text in the .capty-caption with span tag for example and add the style you want.

Answer (score 0):

set css in `div.capty-caption`

in this set `height` or `line-height` property in css  it will helpful

like in `JQUERY.CAPTY.CSS`

```
div.capty-caption {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font: bold 11px verdana;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #222;
    line-height:---SET HERE---; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/UP5xk/4/

i have reduced the `height:50` Check the fiddle script i commented there

Comment: @Rajnikanth did u chek this?